# How do you create a maven assembly that includes shell scripts and properrties file not in jar?

Tags: java, maven, build

Im trying to use Maven to build a standalone application

Using the assembly plugin described at 
[How do you create a standalone application with dependencies intact using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224631/how-do-you-create-a-standalone-application-with-dependencies-intact-using-maven)

This creates widget distribution zip containing

```
widget-1.0
widget-1.0/lib/widget.jar
widget-1.0/lib/3rdpartyjar1.jar
widget-1.0/lib/3rdpartyjar2.jar
```

...

but in my src tree I have:

```
src/main/bin/widget.sh
```

and this doesnt make into the final distribution zip, I would like it to go here

```
widget-1.0/widget.sh
```

Also in my src tree i have a properties file in

```
src/main/properties/widget.properties
```

that currently make its way into

```
widget-1.0/lib/widget.jar
```

but because I want it to be editable I want it to be in

```
widget-1.0/widget.properties
```

Is it possible to do this within maven ?

**EDIT**
Using information in blog got working as follows:

1. Renamed bin folder to scripts folder because this is standard Maven name
2. Moved widget.properties into script folder
3. Modifed my assembly.xml to contain a fileset

Here is the new xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
    <id>distribution</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
            <unpack>false</unpack>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.scriptSourceDirectory}</directory>
            <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>widget.sh</include>
                <include>widget.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

However minor point but unable to find a list of maven standard folder variables anywhere , i.e is there an equivalent to ${project.build.scriptSourceDirectory} for the properties folder

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found [this blog post](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/tips-and-tricks/creating-a-runnable-binary-distribution-with-maven-assembly-plugin/) to be a good tutorial on how to do this.

Also, I think the name of the folder in which you place your files is relevant. Maven obviously does different things with files in `src/main/java` than with files in `src/main/resources`. I'm not 100% sure, but the name of this folder might mean the difference between a file ending up inside the jar or not.

[Here](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-properties.html) is a list of Maven directory name properties.

Comment: thanks looks like a great blog, I'll work through it and see if it solves my problem. Actualy my question was incorrect i store widget.sh in a bin folder, amended question to inidcate this.

Comment: @PaulTaylor I've edited my answer to reflect your edit in the question. Good luck :)!

Comment: @PaulTaylor Cool! I also found you a list of directory variables, BTW, to answer the last part of your question.

Comment: thanks doen;t seem to be a properties varaibles but found could use with ${basedir} instead i.e ${basedir}/src/main/properties

Comment: In case anyone is looking for the resources directory (broken link): ${project.build.sourceDirectory}

Comment: The Maven directory name properties [link](https://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-properties.html) is broken in @jqno s answer. [This](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+Properties+Guide) maybe a replacement, please correct as necessary.

Comment: @DeerWomb Thanks for letting me know about this. I managed to find the new location of the original page I linked to, although yours indeed contains the same information. I updated my answer accordingly.